# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed:

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, daemon, wsl-2

docker run --gpus all -it -v ~/Desktop:/Desktop --ipc=host sangkny/darknet:yolov4 /bin/bash

When I send this command, I get the following error:

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.                                                                              ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

here is my setup:

Windows 10 PRO
Ubuntu 18.04LTS subsystem in WSL2 mode
Docker for desktop v20.10.16

I've tried everything I can with googling, but it hasn't been resolved yet.
I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faced the same problem.

After some hours of Googling eventually I've found a solution - **Windows overdue update to version 21H2**. I came up with that idea after reading [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-21h2#gpu-compute-support-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux):

> Starting with Windows 10 version 21H2, the Windows Subsystem for Linux has full graphics processing unit (GPU) compute support.

Such a pity I lost so much time on it... Hope it helps.